# App can't Navigate to MainPage

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm facing the strange issue on my WP8.1 RT app - one of my beta testers reported that he sees black screen just after the splash screen. The app doesn't crash, hang the phone or other - just black screen instead of MainPage. 
I've implemented some *Trace* methods inside the code to track the issue. The code looks like this:

```cs
// OnLaunched method that gets called when the App starts
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    await Trace.WriteLineAsync(true, "Launched");
    Frame rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
    await Trace.WriteLineAsync(true, "Before - better checkup");
    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        await Trace.WriteLineAsync(false, "Rootframe content was null, navigating");
        if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
            await Trace.WriteLineAsync(false, "Navigation false");
        else await Trace.WriteLineAsync(false, "Navigation was ok");
    }
    await Trace.WriteLineAsync(true, "After - better checkup");
    Window.Current.Activate();
} 

// Method creating the rootFrame:
private Frame CreateRootFrame()
{
    Trace.WriteLineAsync(true, "Create Root frame");
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        Trace.WriteLineAsync(true, "Root frame was null");
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "AppFrame");
        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        Trace.WriteLineAsync(false, "Window content {0}", Window.Current.Content.ToString());
    }
    return rootFrame;
}
```

The log the beta tester gets looks like this:

```
2014-10-06 13:02:56: Launched
2014-10-06 13:02:56: Create Root frame
2014-10-06 13:02:56: Root frame was null
Window content Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame
2014-10-06 13:02:57: Before - better checkup
Rootframe content was null, navigating
Navigation false
2014-10-06 13:02:57: After - better checkup
2014-10-06 13:03:01: App.cs suspending event
```

As you can see **the most important** line is `Navigation false` which means that

```
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
     await Trace.WriteLineAsync(false, "Navigation false");
```

*Navigation* returns false - I cannot navigate within my *Frame*, no crash, no hang - (Suspending event works), just can't get to MainPage. I have complately no idea what can be the source of the problem. Moreover - on my phone everything works, other devices also - both debug & release.

Does anybody have an idea why I cannot navigate to my MainPage?

**Edit** - navogation failed event added:

```
void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    Trace.WriteLineAsync(true, "Failed to load page");
    throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
}
```

Comment: What does the NavigationFailed handler ("OnNavigationFailed") do? Is there an exception reported in the NavigationFailedEventArgs of the event? Does it set Handled to true?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt NavigationFailed (I've added an edit) is not called - no sign of it in the log, also exception is not being thrown - the app doesn't crash.

Comment: I've experienced something similar once, but it was some time ago. IIRC, the problem then involved two static initializers that depended on each other, in combination with async calls (which effectively blocked execution because neither could be initialized). Is there a similar(-ish) scenario in your project?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt I doubt it's the case (I'll take a closer look) - the user can wait few seconds and then click start button - the app is suspended properly - event is called, which means it's not blocked. Also I've put Trace in MainAPge constructor - it doesn't get called - why, I don't know. The case concerns (as for now) only one device, on others it's working just fine.

Comment: Debug the app and see what exceptions are being thrown on attempting to navigate.

Comment: @NateDiamond That's not the problem - debug and release version work just fine on my device. One of beta testers has the problem and I tracked the issue - `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage))` returns *false* - I cannot say why, no exception, nothing, just *false*, even the constructor of the Page is not being called.

Comment: Just because no exception is unhandled and thrown by the Navigate method does not mean that no exception is thrown. If you debug the app and check the debug output, you may see a NullReferenceException or hundred other exceptions being thrown *and then caught* in the Navigate method. It won't make the app crash nor will it trigger the UnhandledException break. Look at the debug output.

Comment: @NateDiamond The biggest problem is that when I debug there is no problem, debug output also doesn't show exceptions.

Comment: @NateDiamond After your comment I've tried to find error elsewhere. It turned out that one of the variables that was initialized before the constructor resulted in exception. The oter thing is that it happened on one phone and it's hard to say why. While debugging and other testing everything seems to be allright. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [Nate Diamond comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215704/app-cant-navigate-to-mainpage#comment41130140_26215704) I started searching for the cause of the problem little different way. I add this answer as it may help someone one day.

Finally after many attempts and help from the beta tester it turned out that the problem was caused by one of the variables that was initialized before the constructor of the Page. The initialization resulted in exception which was swallowed by *Navigate* method and thus it returned false.

The other thing is why the initialization resulted in exception, but that's the other story.